# Can't infer type in the map function

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

As part of migrating my project from angular 5 to 6 I had to update the way RXJS6 does things.

So this

```
this.filteredList = this.autoComplete.valueChanges
.startWith(null)
.map(val => val ? this.filter(val) : this.list.slice());
```

changed to this

```
this.filteredList = this.autoComplete.valueChanges.pipe(
startWith(null),
map(val => val ? this.filter(val) : this.list.slice()));
```

It seems the compiler can't infer type anymore as I get

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2345  (TS) Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of 
type 'string'.
```

I get the same thing on all the `pipeable` operators - none of them can tell the type of the data they are receiving. How do I help it out?

Interestingly enough this seems to be only an intellisense error is the code compiles and works fine.

Comment: `.pipe<OverallResultType>(...)`

Comment: What line throws this error?

Comment: `val` in the `this.filter(val)`. The error only appears in the VS' console. ng server actually compiles fine and the application works correctly.

Comment: Did @jonrsharpe 's comment help you?

Comment: No. Their comment seems to help the `subscribe` function to infer the type but not the pipeable operators.