# Converting rxjs 5 map to rxjs 6 map

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

Consider the following code Angular 5 + older rxjs

```
this.measurementUnitsService.GetAll().subscribe(
        res => {
            this.measurementUnits = res.map(x => new MeasurementUnit(x));
        }
    )
```

I am getting a list of objects and for each one of them creating a new strongly typed class.

How would I go about doing the same in angular 6 + rxjs 6
My attempt.

```
this.measurementUnitsService.GetAll().pipe<MeasurementUnit[]>(mergeMap(x => new MeasurementUnit(x))).subscribe(
  res => {
    this.measurementUnits = res;
  }
)
```

It generates an error unfortunately `Type 'MeasurementUnit[]' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<MeasurementUnit>'.`

`MeasurementUnit` just in case

```
export class MeasurementUnit {
Id: number;
CreatedDate: Date;
ModifiedDate: Date;
Disabled: boolean;
DisabledDate: Date;
Name: string;
Description: string;

ParentId: number;

public constructor(item: Partial<MeasurementUnit>) {
    //item.EstablishedDate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(item.EstablishedDate, "yyyy-MM-dd");

    Object.assign(this, item);
}
}
```

Comment: you are using `mergeMap` instead of `map` . is it intentional ?

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you don't need to change anything at all - you're just mapping an array, not an observable, and RxJS 6 has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @Niladri either one produces the same error. As I was trying different options `map` seems to have produced a worse error so I changed it to `mergeMap`. Now they both prepuce the same error.

Comment: What is the type of `this.measurementUnits`  ? is it  `Partial<MeasurementUnit>`

Comment: @JohnMontgomery ah that makes sense. I am sort of new to the whole observable pattern and I thought map always had something to do with rxjs.

Comment: @Niladri `MeasurementUnit[]`

Comment: @americanslon can you post the code where `this.measurementUnits` is declared

Comment: `public measurementUnits: MeasurementUnit[] = [];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `Observable<MeasurementUnit[]>` not an `Observable<MeasurementUnit>`.

This means, that when the observable emits a value it will be an array not a single value. Hence, you need the normal `array` map, not the `Observable` one.

Just do:

```
this.measurementUnitsService.GetAll()
  .pipe(
    map(array => array.map(x => new MeasurementUnit(x)))
  ).subscribe(res => this.measurementUnits = res);
```

Comment: Makes sense. This does seem like basically the same thing as what I have. Does this produce any benefits vs the original solution (which works) like treeshaking and all that stuff that the pipeable operators are supposed to be better at?

Comment: No, there is not really a difference. It's just the more functional way and doing stuff in the `subscribe` is imperative. If you later want to add more transformations to the `pipe()` operator or you want to use Angular's `async` pipe in your template instead of handling the subscription manually, then this way would be beneficial.

Comment: @americanslon the original code uses rxjs map operator to transform each emitted value of the Observable but inside map you need to use `Array.map` from javascript to transform each emitted array values of the Observable if you are expecting `Observable<MeasurementUnit[]>` from the measurementUnitsService.GetAll() merthod.

Comment: @KimKern your code works but I get an intellisense error on the `array.map`. `Property map doesn't exists on the type {}`. it seems to think `array` is {}. As a matter of fact I have that problem everywhere I use the pipable operators - all of them think the value they are getting is of type {}. I have a whole thread about it if you  'd like to take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845336/cant-infer-type-in-the-map-function

Comment: Can you add `Observable<MeasurementUnit[]>` as the return type to `GetAll` in the `MeasurementUnitsService`?

Comment: I tried with that too. Same thing. I think it's something else since 1. In the code above if you hover over `.GetAll()` the return type is inferred correctly as `Observable<MeasurementUnit[]>` 2. I have this issue everywhere I use pipeable operators, even when dealing with simple types or observables I have no control (and therefore can't set the return type).